# Setting up a basic Gulpfile to run JSDoc

Tags: javascript, gulp, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I am struggling to understand what is missing from my current gulpfile in order to make JSDoc happy.

The code below does not cause any errors to be thrown, but looking at the index page of the documentation that is generated, it is clear my docs have not been formatted.

What am I missing here?

First, here is the function I want to document.

```
/**
 *   Returns the sum of a and b
 *   @param {Number} a
 *   @param {Number} b
 *   @return {Number} Sum of a and b 
 */
var sum = function(a, b){
  return a + b; 
};
```

Next, here is my gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jsdoc = require('gulp-jsdoc');

gulp.task('js-doc', function(){
  return gulp.src([ 'app.js' ])
  .pipe(jsdoc.parser({}, 'test'))
  .pipe(jsdoc.generator('./docs'));
});
```

Once I run `gulp js-doc`, it creates the docs/ directory and builds out the documentation.  However, visiting the index.html page in the browser reveals that no documentation was actually generated.  When I look at `app.js.html`, another file generated by JSDoc, I see my code block but nothing on it has been parsed and turned into actual documentation.  See screenshot below.

[image]

I think I'm missing some fundamental understanding of JSDoc or Gulp.

Comment: I think the problem is in `gulp-jsdoc`, `jsdoc` in both commandline and using `grunt` shows it properly, `gulp-jsdoc` for some reason ignores the global variables, not showing unless it is annotated with `class`, `namespace` or `event`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out:

`npm install --save jsdoc gulp-shell`

Then, inside your gulpfile.js paste in the following requires and task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var shell = require('gulp-shell');

gulp.task('js-doc', shell.task(['./node_modules/jsdoc/jsdoc .']));
```

Now when you run `gulp js-doc` from the command line, you will generate the documentation.

Comment: Just a quick note: For me, I had to use `./node_modules/.bin/jsdoc` instead of `./node_modules/jsdoc/jsdoc` in my gulp task. My shell task ended up being this: `'./node_modules/.bin/jsdoc src -r -d docs'`

Comment: Site is down in your link.  Can you post the contents of your gulpfile for the task?

Comment: Sorry, my domain expired. Posted the answer.